# Android device sleeping issue

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I have a little issue when I set option for device not sleeping. I'm connecting to web server and downloading data and when I'm doing this I need the device stay awake. I'm using this in this way :

1.In my Synchronization class when I start a connection to a web server I set this :

```
PowerManager powerMan = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = powerMan.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
```

and `onDestroy()` method in this activity I set :

```
wl.release();
```

But it seems that after this the device is not sleeping even if I close my application. Is there something that I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this instead of `WakeLock Manager` :

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

this will keep your screen on and you can remove that option by doing his :

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

This should help.